# What can I do to improve a business-oriented network that only has access to 3 6Mb/1.5Mb lines with 15-30 clients?

Tags: networking

I work at an e-commerce based business in a 16k warehouse. The only available ISP solution is AT&T, with each 6Mb/1.5Mb line costing $50 and fiber optic being an option for $800/mo at 20Mb/20Mb.

Around 15 clients are wired throughout the offices, and another 10 or so exist wirelessly.

I know very little about the stack as it was setup before I arrived, but I am very aware of the real problem we have: it's slow. I don't know if it is download (SpeedTest shows 18Mb down), upload (I was told you can only combine download speeds, not uploading speeds, so SpeedTest shows 1.5Mb) or latency (SpeedTest does not show anything abnormal).

We are using a PepLink to load balance the 3 lines into one solution, but I fear it may be set up incorrectly. I don't know how else to explain why the lag that exists is randomly occurring.

What are common solutions here?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: First, you need to define exactly what is slow, and what isnt.  Do only wifi clients have issues?  Only certain websites or applications?

Comment: Enable QoS? Try a different DNS (8.8.8.8) to see if it still lags.

Comment: Put a PC outside of the Peplink and test each circuit for speed & data loss.  This is 1st step to figure out if it's one or more of the circuits or a misconfiguration of the Peplink.  Monitor bandwidth usage, could be as simple as a virus using all of the bandwidth.  Narrow it down...

Answer (score 0):

Where are you located? 
Do you have access to a local consultant?

I'd have someone come out and diagnose the problem based on the information you've provided.

My recommendation would have been a link balancer. I use [Elfiq](http://elfiq.com), but I suppose the [Peplink](http://www.peplink.com) can also work. If it's configured incorrectly, you may be able to call Peplink for help.

In terms of speed, you wouldn't see more than 6Mbps on any given transaction wt the current setup. But it depends on other factors. The right thing to do if you need more bandwidth is to buy the appropriate type of service. I'd still keep an alternative line available for failover.

The wireless is a separate exercise and should be evaluated on its own.

I'm not sure if anyone here can help you without more information, though.